# converting canvas to image doesn't produce right image

Tags: javascript, canvas, coffeescript, html5-canvas

I am converting canvas to image through:

```
tmp_canvas = document.getElementById('myconvas')
dataURL = tmp_canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
$('#PL01_fo').append($('<img/>', { src : dataURL }))
```

Though converted image is not exactly like canvas

canvas:

[image]

After image conversion:

[image]

As you can see, the text in image is different then text in canvas. What can be the problem?

Here is canvas generation code for better understanding:

```
 @octx.fillText $('#text_decoration_text').val(), @w * 0.5, text_h

#/ slide and dice
i = @w
while i--
  y = bottom - (curve * Math.sin(i * @angleSteps * Math.PI / 180))
  @ctx.drawImage @os, i, offsetY, 1, textHeight, i, offsetY, 1, y
return
```

Comment: no library. Just normal html and coffee script.

Comment: Is converting to png doesn't work well with texts? Does the conversion change the Y offset?

Comment: Put coffee in tag question data if you wanna fast answer from somebody who works with coffee script.

Comment: Could include a complete, minimal example here so we can reproduce your bug?

Comment: toDataURL doesn't care of what is rendered on the canvas*, it sees raw rgba values and converts it to the image format you specified => at the time you called toDataURL it is what was rendered on the canvas. But it's unclear when you actually call it.